# how to get file names when processing files in if schema not matching in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have list of files, basically HDFS file_paths and I am reading these files using following

```
file_paths = [hdfs/2022-12-12/file1.json, hdfs/2022-10-10/file2.json, hdfs/2024-02-12/file1.json, hdfs/2020-11-01/file20.json
df_data = spark.read.json(file_paths)
schema = my_schema # I have specific schema in my config
```

I want to make sure that my files in file_path align with my schema. The problem is how to get rejected file names when the schema not matching ? I have tried to keep condition like below

```
for col in df_data.columns:
    if col not in schema.fieldNames():
         rejected.append()

df_data.write.saveAstable(...)
```

Since we are handling everything as dataframe here, can someone let me know how to get the file name where I have schema mismatch ? also I dont want to process the records in that rejected files in my dataframe df_data.